# Is it possible to use an H-bridge IC as dual MOSFET driver?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I've been looking for cheap and easy ways to drive a MOSFET with PWM and I came across a simple 555-based driver.

But that gave me an idea, since push-pull setup is used for driving MOSFETs, and an H bridge is basically a double push-pull, is it possible to use an H bridge motor driver IC, namely the l9110, to drive **two** MOSFETs?

The l9110 is intended to drive one motor, but I think I can connect each output to a MOSFET gate and drive 2 MOSFETs with it.

[Here](https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf) is the datasheet of l9110.

[Another datasheet](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1159321/HMSEMI/L9110B.html). It's in Chinese but has an internal diagram too.

Notes:

- I couldn't find a maximum switching time for l9110 so I know that it probably can't handle more than a few kHz. But that's OK.
- Please don't suggest using a dedicated driver. I'm specifically asking if this particular IC or other H bridge ICs can be used to drive 2 MOSFETs.

Comment: If you're asking about a particular device, it's polite to put a link to the datasheet in your question. If the datsheet doesn't come up on the first page of google searches, then it's ESSENTIAL to link to it, I haven't got time to chase it down through the generic ad-driven datasheet providers.

Comment: @Neil_UK Datasheet links added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if  both external MOSFETs are low-side and only if the external MOSFETs have significantly more gate capacitance than the MOSFETs in the H-bridge IC. And since the MOSFETs in the H-bridge IC already have more gate capacitance than the typical input capacitance of a gate driver it will be slower to begin with.

And only if both MOSFETs don't have to be on at the same time since the L9110 doesn't allow that which you can see from looking at the truth table. This last one is probably a dealbreaker.

Comment: You'd probably be better off building your own gate drive circuit with discrete components.

Comment: Can you explain why the MOSFETs will have to have significantly more gate capacitance? Thanks.

Comment: I managed to find [this](https://pic.17qq.com/uploads/whwrqesqqx.jpeg) internal diagram of the l9110. It appears to be using NPNs instead of MOSFETs. So, good news?

Comment: @PouriaP Bigger MOSFETs = bigger gate capacitance. If it's using BJTs it could be better or could be worse. You do not normally use larger transistors for gate drive because they are slower and do not need to be so big. It's like using your finger to push a button to open an enormous dam, except instead of a small button it is a big 30kg button. As the button approaches the size of the dam it becomes more pointless to have the button.

Comment: I'm confused. Regarding big transistors, the IC can only provide 800mA of current, I wouldn't call that a big transistor. Specially given the fact that MOSFET drivers can provide 1-2Amps. Also regarding the button terminology, I'm actually pushing a button (IC input) that pushes a button (H bridge) that opens the dam (MOSFET). With 800mA of current a MOSFET can switch at ~50kHz, I know that the IC's switching speed will be the limiting factor, but what's the big deal about it? Specially since the alternative is using 3 transistors for **each** MOSFET, while this tiny 8pin IC can drive 2.

Comment: @PouriaP Component count is a separate concern. I'm only talking about performance in driving the MOSFETs. It's more that you know that the H-bridge IC was optimized for something else and wasn't designed as a gate driver which means it probably won't work as well as it could in the application. It's hard to say anything concrete because the L9110 datasheet is so sparse. There's no timing information at all.

Comment: Oh, I also just noticed the L9110 won't allow both MOSFETs to be on at the same time from the truth table in the datasheet.

Comment: Oh, what a bummer. I guess most, if not all, motor drivers have this logic because there's no point driving both outputs high. Which means the answer to my original question is no. Thanks for pointing this out, I was too excited by my "discovery" and I totally overlooked this.

Comment: @PouriaP If you're really in love with the idea you could use each H-bridge IC as a single gate driver. Or use it for a push-pull circuit.

Comment: Hahaha, I truly am! Yeah maybe I'll buy a couple ones and test with different frequencies/currents and see what I get. Don't have an oscilloscope but I might be able to make some crude measurements with a comparator and an MCU.